# How to move from popup page to other pages in windows phone application

Tags: windows-phone-7

I am developing a small game type application,when user wins the game he will get the popup as win for this I wrote the below code.

```
  public void stoptimer()
 {

        if ((Convert.ToString(b1.Content) == "1") && (Convert.ToString(b2.Content) == "2") && (Convert.ToString(b3.Content) == "3") && (Convert.ToString(b4.Content) == "4") && (Convert.ToString(b5.Content) == "5") && (Convert.ToString(b6.Content) == "6") && (Convert.ToString(b7.Content) == "7") && (Convert.ToString(b8.Content) == "8") && (Convert.ToString(b9.Content) == "9") && (Convert.ToString(b10.Content) == "10") && (Convert.ToString(b11.Content) == "11") && (Convert.ToString(b12.Content) == "12") && (Convert.ToString(b13.Content) == "13") && (Convert.ToString(b14.Content) == "14") )

        {
            newTimer.Stop();
            time = txtClock.Text;
            //textBox2.Text = txtClock.Text;
            Popup buyNowScreen;
            buyNowScreen = new Popup();
            buyNowScreen.Child =
                new popupscreen
                    ();
            buyNowScreen.IsOpen = true;
            buyNowScreen.VerticalOffset = 100;
            buyNowScreen.HorizontalOffset = 25;

        }
      }
```

And  I wrote the below code for navigate from popup page to other pages but it is not working getting the NullReferenceException.

```
   private void button3_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        ClosePopup();
        NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Menu.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ClosePopup();

        NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/NumericEasy.xaml", UriKind.Relative));

    }


    private void ClosePopup()
    {
        Popup buyPop = this.Parent as Popup;
        if (buyPop.IsOpen)
        {
            buyPop.IsOpen = false;


        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the procedure for giving events to popup page's controls.

```
    Popup buyNowScreen=new Popup();

    popupscreen popup1=new popscreen();
    buyNowScreen.Child =popup1;
    buyNowScreen.isOpen=true;
    popup1.button1.click+= new RoutedEventHandler(btn_playagain_click);
    private void btn_playagain_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
        p.IsOpen = false;
        NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/NumericEasy.xaml?Refresh=true", UriKind.Relative));
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Navigation service works between pages, you cant use a popup so simple. This service can't find, what page to use, that's why it's throwing an exception.

To solve your problem, you should do this:

**Popup class**

1)At your popup constructor you should get PhoneApplicationPage object.

```
      private PhoneApplicationPage _page;

      public SomePopup(PhoneApplicationPage page)
            {
             _page = page;
```

2) You should create a new type for click event.

```
        public delegate void NavigateHandler(object sender, EventArgs e, PhoneApplicationPage page);

        public event NavigateHandler NavigateFromPopup;
```

3) At your button_click event you should call it:

```
public void ButtonX_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
               if (NavigateFromPopup!= null)
                NavigateFromPopup(this, EventArgs.Empty, _page);
        }
```

---

**Your page class**

4) At your page, when you create a popup, you should add this eventHandler:

```
            SomePopup p = new SomePopup(this);
            p.NavigateFromPopup +=new SomePopup.NavigateHandler(p_NavigateFromPopup);
```

5) And finally, at your page you should write down this event:

```
private void p_NavigateFromPopup(object sender, EventArgs e, PhoneApplicationPage page)
        {
            page.NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("...", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
        }
```

That should work.